# React, How to put a div onto the bottom of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I wrote a component that get data from server, and an extra tip box is needed to show details for these data, this component is in an unknown-size div.Just like picture below.

```
------------------------------------
|        |                |        |
|        |                |        |
|        |                | Parent |
|        | -------        |  view  |
|        | | Tip |        |        |
|        | -------        |        |
---------|----------------|---------
         |                |
         |                |
         |     Content    |
         |                |
         |                |
         ------------------
```

Background: there is a parent view area to show my component with content, but  the size of parent view is unknown, in the meanwhile, content may contains several data, so a tip box is needed to show the detail of each data. The parent view is using `overflow-y=scroll` style.

My problem:

1. The tip box should be created by content-component
2. If the height of content-component is higher than parent view like picture above, my tip box should be at the bottom of parent view

I am very confusions with this case, so would it be OK for you to give me a way to do it?

Comment: Please add code sample with

Comment: I have almost no idea about it, so...

Answer (score 0):

the way I generally approach these kinds of issues is to create an example tooltip with content in the component's state, render it in place as required.

Once it looks like it should I then create a function to fetch the data from where it should actually come from and store it in the same component state when it arrives. I then switch the rendering to only display when the data is available so that it only shows up conditionally.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but maybe you could explain why the approach above doesn't work for you (if you have already thought about it), and we can figure it out from there.